# Open app on a specific monitor in GNOME

Tags: gnome, multiple-monitors, display

I'm trying to follow some instructions on getting specific software to open up on a specific monitor in GNOME. I have three monitors. xrandr -q output is as follows:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 5040 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
DVI-D-0 connected 1440x900+3600+79 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 408mm x 255mm
   1440x900      59.89*+  74.98  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    72.19    60.32    56.25  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    59.94  
HDMI-0 connected primary 1920x1080+1680+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 521mm x 293mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  59.94    50.00    60.00    50.04  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1440x576      50.00  
   1440x480      59.94  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94    50.00  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    72.19    60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    59.94    59.93  
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-3 connected 1680x1050+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 433mm x 271mm
   1680x1050     59.88*+  59.95  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   640x480       75.00    59.94  
   640x350       70.07  
DP-4 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-5 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

I'm running 18.04, using Xorg for display, and nVidia 396.

I've tried prepending DISPLAY=":0", or DISPLAY=":0.0", with numerical variations between 0 to 3 for each type. Each time, I get either this message:

```
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
# Failed to parse arguments: Cannot open display:
```

Or this one:

```
# Error creating terminal: Failed to get screen from object path /org/gnome/Terminal/screen/47543056_45c7_42eb_8d4e_1277fad5286e
```

I've also tried using the --geometry option. I thought perhaps adding the following option would open what I need in the left monitor:

```
--geometry=1680x1050+0+0
```

However, this just opens up the relevant software maximised in the primary (centre) monitor. Even after trying varying resolutions and offsets, the result would still be the same.

This is really only a minor inconvenience for me, so I don't want to install any additional packages if that's the only way around this, but if I'm using the wrong commands, let me know what I should be using instead.

Essentially, I want to open two terminals. One on my left and right monitors in full screen. To that extent, the base command I use is:

```
gnome-terminal --full-screen
```

Comment: Which Ubuntu version and, more importantly, which display server (Xorg/Wayland)?

Comment: 18.04, Xorg, and if it matters, nVidia 396. Edited into the post.

Comment: Have you tried `--geometry...` without `--fullscreen`?

Comment: Yes. The --full-screen option is something I'd want to use afterwards. I'd figure if the geometry is set so that the terminal appears anywhere on a specific monitor, the full-screen option would take care of filling up the rest of the space.

Comment: the width and height are specified as number of columns and lines, not pixels. Try `--geometry 1x1+0+0 --full-screen`.

Comment: Well would you look at that! I knew there was some minor detail I was missing! Thanks for that. If you want to put that as an answer, I'll go ahead and accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were on the right track. The `--full-screen` option will open the terminal window in full screen mode on the monitor it is displayed on in the first place. But on which monitor is `gnome-terminal` displayed? Using the `geometry` parameter, you can specify width, height, and x/y offset:

```
gnome-terminal --geometry WidthxHeight+Xoffset+Yoffset
```

...where the offsets are specified in pixels, but **width and height are specified in number of columns and lines**, respectively. The window will never span multiple monitors and will be placed on the monitor that would contain the biggest part of the window if it spanned multiple monitors.

In your case, despite 0 offset, you made the window **1680 columns wide**, which is why it was placed on the middle monitor.

When you want to display the terminal in full screen anyways, use the smallest possible dimensions to ensure that it is placed on the correct monitor in the first place:

```
#left monitor:
gnome-terminal --geometry 1x1+0+0 --full-screen

#right monitor:
gnome-terminal --geometry 1x1+3600+0 --full-screen
```