# Opening a full screen application on a specific window

Tags: xorg, wine, multiple-monitors

Running 19.04, with a triple monitor setup. I open games full screen on my centre monitor with Wine, simply by running `wine game.exe`. However, Wine recently updated, and now it's opening on my left-most monitor. How can I get it back to opening on my centre monitor?

I've tried using the `--geometry` option at the end of my Wine command, but it doesn't seem to make a difference. The software still opens in the same spot.

The centre monitor is also confirmed as the primary monitor.

Using Nvidia driver 430.26.

---

If I recall, X does not create separate screens for each monitor. Rather, it combines the monitors into one logical screen. Looking at `nvidia-settings`, I see X Screen 0 shown as 5040x1086. My three monitors are set to 1680x1050, 1920x1080, and 1440x900, from left to right.

I don't know if this is how X Server has always done it, but perhaps my issue could be solved if each monitor was its own separate screen. Is there a way to do that? Or is there a better/simpler solution to this problem?

I had asked a [similar question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1062148/opening-software-on-a-specific-monitor) almost a year ago, regarding how to open a terminal on a specific monitor. Unfortunately, the same method does not seem to apply to the situation here.

---

EDIT:

Information as shown by `nvidia-settings` indicates that `X Screen 0`, which contains my three monitors, has a display name of `hiigaran:0.0`.

As per earthmeLon's suggestion, I attempted to prepend `SDL_VIDEO_FULLSCREEN_HEAD` to the command I wished to use to start the application in question. The following three commands were used to test which monitor the application would open on:

```
SDL_VIDEO_FULLSCREEN_HEAD=0 wine game.exe
SDL_VIDEO_FULLSCREEN_HEAD=1 wine game.exe
SDL_VIDEO_FULLSCREEN_HEAD=2 wine game.exe
```

No difference was observed between using any of these commands, and using `wine game.exe` on its own. The application still opened full screen on the left-most monitor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it seems running Wine in a virtual desktop is the way to go. I had been avoiding doing this, because if I were to set the desktop to the resolution of the monitor I'd want to use it on, the virtual desktop's title bar, combined with Ubuntu's top/activity bar would cause a decent portion of the virtual desktop to be cut off at the bottom. Plus the dock would make things worse.

After fiddling around for a bit, the best solution I have come up with is as follows:

1. Ensure hotkeys are set in `gnome-control-center` at Settings > Devices > Keyboard, for moving windows to a different monitor, and for entering full screen
2. Start your desired program with Wine as per normal
3. When the virtual desktop appears and takes focus, use your hotkeys to move the window to the desired monitor.
4. Use your full screen hotkey to get the virtual desktop to use the entire monitor area

While it would have been ideal for software to open already full screen on the correct monitor, this has been a suitable solution for me, though technically, it's more of a workaround, than an actual solution.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, you use a single Screen, and all of your monitors belong to that one Screen, as you're seeing.  By using multiple Screens, you can more accurately define where applications load, but you cannot move applications between different Screens.

If you were using multiple Screens, you would determine which Screen via the `DISPLAY` variable:

```bsh
DISPLAY=:1 wine
```

To set which monitor is used for full screen applications, as well as to ensure that all monitors aren't used altogether for full screen applications, I've had the most luck setting the `SDL_VIDEO_FULLSCREEN_HEAD` environment variable so that this is available within the window manager.  You set it to the number of your monitor, starting with zero:

```bsh
export SDL_VIDEO_FULLSCREEN_HEAD=0
```

With three monitors, you can choose between `0`, `1` and `2`.  You can set this in `~/.xinitrc` / `~/.xsessionrc`.  Where you place this `export` is highly dependent on how your window manager starts up, using GDM, LightDM, or `startx`, etc.

You can test if this may work for you, or which monitor is which, by setting the variable at runtime:

```bsh
$ SDL_VIDEO_FULLSCREEN_HEAD=1 wine
```

*Note:* OP mentions this testing does not work.

---

It may make sense to also set this as your default monitor, or ensure it is **not** your default monitor.  The default monitor can be set with `xrandr`:

```bsh
$ xrandr primary NAME_OF_DEVICE
```

---

#### Wine Virtual Desktop

If all of this fails, you have the final option of configuring Wine to use a virtual desktop.  This will cause Wine to create a Windows window, and you are able to specify the resolution of this window (to match your monitor's resolution).  Full screen Windows applications run via Wine will then fill that window only.  You can use your Window Manager to move this to the correct desktop/monitor.

This can be done opening Wine Configuration (winecfg) and opening the Graphics tab, or by using the `/desktop=name,1024x768` flag when running wine:

```
wine /desktop=name,1024x768 game.exe
```

Comment: nvidia-settings shows one screen, with the three monitors contained within them. This screen is shown with the display name of hiigaran:0.0. Not sure what to do with that information, though. In any case, I tried setting the fullscreen_head variable on runtime with 0, 1, and 2. In all three cases, no difference was made. The software was still opening as described in my question.

Comment: Can you please update your question to include the exact commands you ran, where you set this variable?

Comment: Done. Any other information required?

Comment: Thank you for trying and showing results.  I can only recommend getting this set earlier on and testing that it doesn't work in that case.  Best of luck and I hope you find a better answer, but I updated with one final way of picking your monitor for Wine applications, specifically.

Comment: The virtual desktop is about as close as I can get. It's a good enough temporary workaround, but there will be part of the screen cut off by using a virtual desktop. It's similar to when I use Ubuntu's shortcut keys to move the fullscreen application to the centre monitor with the appropriate hotkey. I can hide the dock, but the activity bar remains visible, and I can't get rid of it.