# How to keep an app on one screen

Tags: gnome, multiple-monitors

I am using a HTPC running Ubuntu 19.04; my main app is Kodi, and I want to be on the large monitor (Screen 1).

I want all the other stuff including the sidebar to be on screen 2, no matter what. Even if screen 1 is off, I don't want Kodi on screen 2, nor if screen 2 is off, I don't want any other apps on screen 1.

Not seeing an easy way to do that. Any suggestions would be great. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open app on a specific monitor in GNOME](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1062148/open-app-on-a-specific-monitor-in-gnome)

Comment: get the id of the window id substitute $name for  Kodi =$(xdotool search --desktop 0 --class  "$name")

Comment: hints  - this is how I send windows to the other monitor get the id of the window id substitute $name for  Kodi --- $(xdotool search --desktop 0 --class  "$name")          then send keys to move to other monitor   -  xdotool windowactivate --sync $id key  --clearmodifiers  --delay 100 ctrl+alt+shift+plus - crl alt shift plus is what I have set in powerkey, keyboard, keyboard, shortcuts, 'move window on monitor to the left'   --  so in your case you might get all the windows (?how * ), send them all to screen 2, and send Kodi to screen 1   .

Comment: xdotool has get_num_desktops to check if screen 2 is off, if it is then minimise instread of send to other window all except Kodi.
for a finite set of windows               names="Firefox Thunderbird Kate Konsole"                                                              
for    name in $names
    do         id=$(xdotool search --desktop 0 --class  "$name")